# TypeError: The JSON content is required to be a `dict`, but found <class 'list'>

Tags: tensorflow.js

when I run "tensorflowjs_converter" in Python 3.7.
It reported error:

> TypeError: The JSON content is required to be a dict, but found class'list'.

I want to transform the file of json to keras_save_model:

```
tensorflowjs_converter --input_format tfjs_layers_model --output_format keras_saved_model tiny_face_js/tiny_face_detector_model-weights_manifest.json tiny_face_h5
```

But it failed, I looks into the json file.

> [{"weights":[{"name":"conv0/filters","shape":[3,3,3,16],"dtype":"float32","quantization":{"dtype":"uint8","scale":0.009007044399485869,"min":-1.2069439495311063}},{"name":"conv0/bias","shape":[16],"dtype":"float32","quantization":{"dtype":"uint8","scale":0.005263455241334205,"min":-0.9211046672334858}},{"name":"conv1/depthwise_filter","shape":[3,3,16,1],"dtype":"float32","quantization":{"dtype":"uint8","scale":0.004001977630690033,"min":-0.5042491814669441}},{"name":"conv1/pointwise_filter","shape":[1,1,16,32],"dtype":"float32","quantization":{"dtype":"uint8","scale":0.013836609615999109,"min":-1.411334180831909}},{"name":"conv1/bias","shape":[32],"dtype":"float32","quantization":{"dtype":"uint8","scale":0.0015159862590771096,"min":-0.30926119685173037}},{"name":"conv2/depthwise_filter","shape":[3,3,32,1],"dtype":"float32","quantization":{"dtype":"uint8","scale":0.002666276225856706,"min":-0.317286870876948}},{"name":"conv2/pointwise_filter","shape":[1,1,32,64],"dtype":"float32","quantization":{"dtype":"uint8","scale":0.015265831292844286,"min":-1.6792414422128714}},{"name":"conv2/bias","shape":[64],"dtype":"float32","quantization":{"dtype":"uint8","scale":0.0020280554598453,"min":-0.37113414915168985}},{"name":"conv3/depthwise_filter","shape":[3,3,64,1],"dtype":"float32","quantization":{"dtype":"uint8","scale":0.006100742489683862,"min":-0.8907084034938438}},{"name":"conv3/pointwise_filter","shape":[1,1,64,128],"dtype":"float32","quantization":{"dtype":"uint8","scale":0.016276211832083907,"min":-2.0508026908425725}},{"name":"conv3/bias","shape":[128],"dtype":"float32","quantization":{"dtype":"uint8","scale":0.003394414279975143,"min":-0.7637432129944072}},{"name":"conv4/depthwise_filter","shape":[3,3,128,1],"dtype":"float32","quantization":{"dtype":"uint8","scale":0.006716050119961009,"min":-0.8059260143953211}},{"name":"conv4/pointwise_filter","shape":[1,1,128,256],"dtype":"float32","quantization":{"dtype":"uint8","scale":0.021875603993733724,"min":-2.8875797271728514}},{"name":"conv4/bias","shape":[256],"dtype":"float32","quantization":{"dtype":"uint8","scale":0.0041141652009066415,"min":-0.8187188749804216}},{"name":"conv5/depthwise_filter","shape":[3,3,256,1],"dtype":"float32","quantization":{"dtype":"uint8","scale":0.008423839597141042,"min":-0.9013508368940915}},{"name":"conv5/pointwise_filter","shape":[1,1,256,512],"dtype":"float32","quantization":{"dtype":"uint8","scale":0.030007277283014035,"min":-3.8709387695088107}},{"name":"conv5/bias","shape":[512],"dtype":"float32","quantization":{"dtype":"uint8","scale":0.008402082966823203,"min":-1.4871686851277068}},{"name":"conv8/filters","shape":[1,1,512,25],"dtype":"float32","quantization":{"dtype":"uint8","scale":0.028336129469030042,"min":-4.675461362389957}},{"name":"conv8/bias","shape":[25],"dtype":"float32","quantization":{"dtype":"uint8","scale":0.002268134028303857,"min":-0.41053225912299807}}],"paths":["tiny_face_detector_model-shard1"]}]

I tried to delete the "[]", it reports:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "e:\users\admin\anaconda3\envs\ai_python3.7\lib\runpy.py", line 193,
>   in _run_module_as_main
>       "**main**", mod_spec)   File "e:\users\admin\anaconda3\envs\ai_python3.7\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in
>   _run_code
>       exec(code, run_globals)   File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts\tensorflowjs_converter.exe__main__.py",
>   line 7, in    File
>   "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflowjs\converters\converter.py",
>   line 638, in pip_main
>       main([' '.join(sys.argv[1:])])   File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflowjs\converters\converter.py",
>   line 642, in main
>       convert(argv[0].split(' '))   File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflowjs\converters\converter.py",
>   line 605, in convert
>       args.output_path)   File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflowjs\converters\converter.py",
>   line 257, in dispatch_tensorflowjs_to_keras_saved_model_conversion
>       model = keras_tfjs_loader.load_keras_model(config_json_path)   File
>   "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflowjs\converters\keras_tfjs_loader.py",
>   line 194, in load_keras_model
>       _check_config_json(config_json)   File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflowjs\converters\keras_tfjs_loader.py",
>   line 96, in _check_config_json
>       raise KeyError('Field "modelTopology" is missing from the JSON content.') KeyError: 'Field "modelTopology" is missing from the JSON
>   content.'
>   Is there any workaround to resolve the problem?

Thanks & Regards!
Jun Yan

Comment: It is not the `manifest.json` that you put as parameter but rather the `model.json` that contains the model topology.

Answer (score 0):

When you specify `tfjs_layers_model` as input format, the input should be `model.json` generated by tfjs-converter in advance. The format looks as follows.

```
{
  "format": "layers-model",
  "generatedBy": "1.13.1",
  "convertedBy": "TensorFlow.js Converter v1.4.0",
  "userDefinedMetadata": {
    //...
  }
}
```

One note is that `tfjs_layers_model` is only created from `keras` or `keras_saved_model`, `tf_saved_model` is not supported for the layers model. The command to create layers model may look like this.

```
$ tensorflowjs_converter \
    --input_format=keras \
    --output_format=tfjs_layers_model \
    /path/to/keras_model \
    /path/to/tfjs_model
```

Then you can recreate keras model like this.

```
$ tensorflowjs_converter \
    --input_format tfjs_layers_model \
    --output_format keras_saved_model \
    /path/to/tfjs_model/model.json \
    /path/to/tiny_face_h5
```

See for more detail: [Converting a TensorFlow SavedModel, TensorFlow Hub module, Keras HDF5 or tf.keras SavedModel to a web-friendly format](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/tree/master/tfjs-converter#step-1-converting-a-tensorflow-savedmodel-tensorflow-hub-module-keras-hdf5-or-tfkeras-savedmodel-to-a-web-friendly-format)